# paste and use a oauth2 access token

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, sinatra

I have an application using ruby and sinatra. I want to be able to paste a token which is in this format:

```
{"access_token":"token...uwD--Of0ikNjr8AeW3oS9zP2rith3fdsf2Wk","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"created":1415727521}
```

into a text-area and use it. Now the problem is, the pasted token is in string format. I have tried converting it into an hash and also to json format but it ain't working still. 
Here is my code:

```
post '/tokenize' do
  got_token = params[:token] # the pasted token
  token_hash = JSON.parse(got_token) #I am not sure if I did this correctly.but it is producing an hash.
  token = token_hash.to_json # producing the token in json format as the original token that I pasted.
  get_contacts(JSON.parse(token)) # calling the function that should use the token. giving an error since it is not a valid oauth token.
 redirect to ("/tokenize/finish")
end
```

Error: It is producing an error because the token is not a valid oauth token.
Someone please tell me how I make the token valid and usable.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually instantiate token class OAuth2::AccessToken with params that you have collected full definition of that constructour you can [find here](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/blob/master/lib/oauth2/access_token.rb#L26-L53).

But eventually you will need OAuth2 client for using that manually instantiated.

For example:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new('client_id', 'client_secret', :site => 'https://example.org')

token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(client, collected_token, collected_opts)

response = token.get('/api/resource', :params => { 'query_foo' => 'bar' })
```